# ExtJs in a ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, extjs

I would like to understand if it is possible to use ExtJs as is (without any modification) in a web application built with asp.net server technology.
practically I would like to develop a Web application with ASP.NET using ExtJs as is, but I don't know if I can use it without problems of licensing.
Thanks in advance
Luke

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about it from the technical perspective, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719137/using-extjs-with-asp-net-webforms-or-mvc/1719569#1719569).

If you are asking about licensing specifically (and I'm assuming you're asking about GPL) you can use it as long as your application is compatible with GPL.  If you have any doubts you should email licensing@sencha.com.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992391/is-this-scenario-in-compliance-with-gplv3) for some insight about Ext + GPL.

You should also look into [Ext.NET](http://www.ext.net/) if you haven't already -- they are the official Sencha .NET partner and offer the same dual licensing model as Ext JS.

EDIT: Any answer you get here will just be someone's opinion -- it will not be a basis for you to defend against an infringement claim by Sencha that you have violated their licensing.  You really should contact the company if you have any doubts -- see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992391/is-this-scenario-in-compliance-with-gplv3/2992959#2992959), including the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Actually my problem is concerning license of ExtJs and specifically GPL.
Let's say in another way: Is it a web application developed with ASP.NET compatible with GPL license?
Since an ASP.NET application has a server part binary files,in C# for example, I can imagine this part is a closed-source software, right?
So the server side binary files are part of my web application and if I didn't distribute them with source code, I would violate GPL, obviuosly using ExtJs.
Please tell me if I am arguing well.